# Open Api Swagger Getting 404

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am trying to access swagger ui via http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html to reach endpoint templates but getting 404.

I have just added latest version of open api.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.9</version>
</dependency>
```

I gave permission to swagger endpoints like below.

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
            .cors()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(handler).and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/auth/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/swagger-ui/index.html", "/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

    httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

and I added Annotation to my main class;

```
@SpringBootApplication
@OpenAPIDefinition
public class DmsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DmsApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: As it is an error 404 it seems like that endpoint does not exist. Do you have spring.application.name set to something in your application.properties file or are you running on another port than 8080?

Comment: No I didnt change port with application yaml or properties

Comment: I can react http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs :) but I cannot reach http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html :(

Comment: Same here, did you figure out what is the problem ?, btw the code base, working on other machines, but not mine !

Comment: @Bertug I am facing the same problem .do you find any fix?